# How can I use roads from OSM data in R?

Tags: openstreetmap, r, gps, distance, road

I need to use the roads to compare GPS positions to verify that they are no errors in the data.

I downloaded the map.osm from a site that have information of City of Rome and had it transformed to Spatial Lines in R.

```
src <- osmsource_file(file = "rome.osm")
bb <- center_bbox(41.9, 12.3, 1000, 1000)
rome <- get_osm(bb, src)
ways <- find(rome, way(tags(k == "highway")))
ways <- find_down(rome, way(ways))
ways <- subset(rome, ids = ways)
hw_lines <- as_sp(ways, "lines")
```

So with the Spatial Lines Object I tried to use  distm function but It's accused that the spatial object can't be used (not is in a suitable format).

There is another way using OSM to get information of only roads that I can compare with GPS data in R?

Comment: What's the `distm` function? Can you show what you tried and the error message? Are you trying to compute distances from some points to the nearest point on the road network?

Comment: `distm` is a function from package geosphere in R, it calculates the distance betweeen point to point or point to Spatial Object, returning a matrix in the second case.
` a <- distm(c(taxi$lat[1], taxi$lon[1]), hw_lines, fun = distHaversine)`
The error says "Error in .pointsToMatrix(y) : 
  points should be vectors of length 2, matrices with 2 columns, or inheriting from a SpatialPoints* object".
`as_sp` from osmar package convert the OSM object loaded to a Spatial Object.
`> class(hw_lines)`
`[1] "SpatialLinesDataFrame"`
`attr(,"package")`
`[1] "sp"`

Answer (score 8):

I downloaded a dataset from the City of Rome using the `osmar` package. After that, I followed your query to get the desired *highways* and then build a random *SpatialPoints* object inside Rome bounding box retrieved data. I measured distances between points and lines using the function `dist2line` from the `geosphere` package.

Please, try the code below:

```
# Load libraries
library('osmar')
library('geosphere')

# Define the spatial extend of the OSM data we want to retrieve
rome.box <- center_bbox(center_lon = 12.5450, center_lat = 41.8992, width =  2000, height = 2000)

# Download all osm data inside this area
api <- osmsource_api()
rome <- get_osm(rome.box, source = api)

# General plot
plot(rome)

# Find highways
ways <- find(rome, way(tags(k == "highway")))
ways <- find_down(rome, way(ways))
ways <- subset(rome, ids = ways)

# SpatialLinesDataFrame object
hw_lines <- as_sp(ways, "lines")  

# Plot
spplot(hw_lines, zcol = "uid")

# Interactive view
mapview::mapview(hw_lines) 

# Make a random points dataset (like GPS)
gpsPoints <- spsample(x = hw_lines, n = 100, type = "random")

# Plot points
plot(hw_lines, xlab = "Lon", ylab = "Lat")
plot(gpsPoints, add = TRUE, pch = 19, col = "red")
box()

# Distances between Higways and random points
distances <- dist2Line(p = gpsPoints, line = hw_lines)
```

[image: romehighways]

Comment: I tried to use `api <- osmsource_api()` but they said that the bbox have too many points so I tried to download a .osm file.
I've used rome.osm from [http://metro.teczno.com/#rome](http://metro.teczno.com/#rome).
I don't understand, in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome) says that Rome coordinates are 41°54′N 12°30′E and in [OSM Rome](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=41.889%2C%2012.48#map=12/41.8890/12.4801) says it's 41°889'N 12°48'E, yet you used a different coordinates for your rome.box. 
`get_osm()` have a different coordinates sistem?

Comment: @FabioJojima I'm sorry, It was an error! I found "Rome" as a city in USA! I updated the answer. Please check if it now answer your question!

Comment: I found that the optional call to `mapview` didn't work because our **Rcpp** routines didn't support 'POSIX*' objects. Anyway, the issue is solved now on the [GitHub develop branch](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview/tree/develop) and will be available with the next official update on CRAN.

Comment: I get an error executing `get_osm(rome.box, source = api)` saying `Space required after the Public Identifier`. There is an answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428697/error-in-osmarget-osm) on how to fix it.

Comment: osmar library is now discontinued - can this approach be modified for the osmdata library?