# Why does R's osmar::get_osm throw an error?

Tags: r, openstreetmap

May be this is obvious, but I was not able to find a solution:
I just copied the code from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218306/121504)

```
library('osmar')
library('geosphere')
rome.box <- center_bbox(center_lon = 12.5450, center_lat = 41.8992, width =  2000, height = 2000)
api <- osmsource_api()
rome <- get_osm(rome.box, source = api)
```

but the resulting output / error message is

> Space required after the Public Identifier SystemLiteral " or '
>   expected SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing Opening and ending tag
>   mismatch: hr line 7 and body Opening and ending tag mismatch: body
>   line 4 and html Premature end of data in tag html line 2
>   Fehler:
>   1:  Space required after the Public Identifier
>   2: SystemLiteral " or ' expected
>   3: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing
>   4: Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 7 and body 
>   5: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 4 and html
>   6: Premature end of data in tag html line 2

What is wrong?

PS: I am a beginner with GIS...

Comment: Hi! I've never used osmar so I cannot help on that specific error bit maybe I can help you download data from OSM. What are you trying to achieve with that code?

Comment: @agila: The overall goal is the following: 1) Add "points" and "ways" to an `.osm` file
2) Read that `.osm` file, extract "points" and "ways" to be able to calculate a distance matrix. (Your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011890/5784831) showed me one way to read an ".osm" file, but unfortunately, it seems, it does not extract the "highways", see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/363315/121504)) 3) Merge the two ".osm" files in one 4) Merge the two distance matrices (I hope, this is easy). If you like, I post this as question, but I can't provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi! I think I answered the other question but, unfortunately, it's quite difficult to be more precise without further details on the problem. for example: what do you mean by "add" points and ways to an .osm file? What do you mean by distance matrix? How can you merge the distance matrix? IMO the easiest solution is to post each step as a separate question with as many details as possible (but of course I don't know your problem)