# Can I extract the `highway` layer using R's sf-package?

Tags: r, openstreetmap

From [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osmdata/vignettes/osm-sf-translation.html#42_osm_ways)
it seems this is not possible:

> osmdata returns all ways, and thus enables, for example, examination
>   of the full attributes of any  member of a multigeometry object. This
>   is not possible with the `GDAL/sf` translation. As for points,  the
>   only additional difference between osmdata and `GDAL/sf` is that
>   osmdata retains all key-value  pairs, whereas GDAL retains only a
>   select few.

Which packages can select highways? I found an answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218306/121504), but this is [not working in my case](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/363307/121504)

In a first step, I want to display the highways on a map...

---

**Edit**: It seems I get closer - almost without using `library(osmdata)`...

```
library(sf) # Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
sf::st_layers("myfile.osm", options = c("USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"))

options:        USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO 
Driver: OSM 
Available layers:
        layer_name       geometry_type features fields
1           points               Point       NA     10
2            lines         Line String       NA      9
3 multilinestrings   Multi Line String       NA      4
4    multipolygons       Multi Polygon       NA     25
5  other_relations Geometry Collection       NA      4
```

and

```
ims <- sf::st_read("myfile.osm", options = c("USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"), layer = "lines")
options:        USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO 
Reading layer `lines' from data source `C:\myfile.osm' using driver `OSM'
Simple feature collection with 47 features and 9 fields
geometry type:  LINESTRING
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 7.554 ymin: 50.20 xmax: 7.564 ymax: 50.2
geographic CRS: WGS 84
```

Then

```
ims <- sf::st_transform(ims, crs = 4326)
my_bbox <- sf::st_bbox(ims) 
ims <- ims %>% osmdata::opq(my_bbox) %>% sf::add_osm_features(key = "highway")
bb_poly has more than one polygon; the first will be selected.
 Error in bbox[, 2] : Indixing out of bounds
```

---

**The solution**

```
ims <- sf::st_read("myfile.osm", options = c("USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"), 
                   layer = "points") # Those are the points
ims <- sf::st_read("myfile.osm", options = c("USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"), 
                   layer = "lines") # That is the highway!!
# ims <- sf::st_read("myfile.osm", options = c("USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"), 
#                    layer = "multilinestrings") # does not work
ims <- sf::st_read("myfile.osm", options = c("USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"), 
                   layer = "multipolygons")
# ims <- sf::st_read("myfile", options = c("USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"), 
#                    layer = "other_relations") # does not work

ims <- sf::st_transform(ims, crs = 4326)
ims_geom <- sf::st_geometry(ims)
plot(st_geometry(ims_geom))
```

Comment: Hi! IMO the problem here is that you are mixing two different approaches. If you don't have a `.osm` file and you want to download the data from Open Street Map Servers you should use the `osmdata` approach that I explained in the following answer. If you have already download a `.osm` file and you want to load that .osm file into R, you can use the `sf::st_read` approach. You can't mix them, i.e. `ims <- sf:.st_read(...); ims %>% add_osm_feature` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What I mean is that if you are interesting in download data for a particular city (like Padova), then you should write: `opq("Padova, Italy") %>% add_osm_feature(key = "highway")`. You cannot use `ims` as the input of `add_osm_feature`.

Comment: The first step is to import in R your osm file. Can you test `sf::st_read("myfile.osm", options = c("USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"))` and report the output? Please note that I misspecified the option command in the previous comment.

Comment: OK, awesome, so you can successfully read the .osm file! If you want to eliminate that warning message you should simply select one of the layers in the .osm file. Now if you can to download the Open Street Map highway data for that area you should run something like: `my_bbox <- sf::st_bbox(ims)` and then `opq(my_bbox) %>% add_osm_features(key = "highway")`. You should also check the CRS code of `ims` since it's EPSG code should be 4326. If it's not specified in this way you can change to CRS using `ims <- st_transform(ims, crs = 4326)`.

Comment: Can you add the output of sf::st_bbox(ims)?

Comment: Solved! See my edit. If you like, you can add this to your answer ;-) Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code downloads from OSM servers all highways in a bounding box around Castellon (ES). The first step is loading some R packages

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(osmdata)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
```

then I download highway data for Castellon de la Plana, ES (where I live now)

```r
highways_castellon <- opq("Castellon de la Plana, ES") %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway") %>% 
  osmdata_sf()

# Print the result
highways_castellon
#> Object of class 'osmdata' with:
#>                  $bbox : 39.8739213,-0.1644067,40.0644134,0.6902931
#>         $overpass_call : The call submitted to the overpass API
#>                  $meta : metadata including timestamp and version numbers
#>            $osm_points : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 95973 points
#>             $osm_lines : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 17708 linestrings
#>          $osm_polygons : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 416 polygons
#>        $osm_multilines : NULL
#>     $osm_multipolygons : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 11 multipolygons
```

The result is an `osmdata_sf` object

```r
class(highways_castellon)
#> [1] "list"       "osmdata"    "osmdata_sf"
```

with 95973 POINTS, 17708 LINESTRINGS, 416 POLYGONS and 11 MULTIPOLYGONS. You can read the meaning of these terms on the vignettes of the osmdata packages. Moreover osmdata implements a function called osm_poly2line to transform circular linestrings (such as roundabouts, which are usually represented as polygons) into regular linestrings. Check more details on `?osmdata::osm_poly2line`. I also recently submitted a paper on a similar topic and will share that as soon as possible.

```r
highways_castellon <- osm_poly2line(highways_castellon)

# Print the result
highways_castellon
#> Object of class 'osmdata' with:
#>                  $bbox : 39.8739213,-0.1644067,40.0644134,0.6902931
#>         $overpass_call : The call submitted to the overpass API
#>                  $meta : metadata including timestamp and version numbers
#>            $osm_points : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 95973 points
#>             $osm_lines : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 18124 linestrings
#>          $osm_polygons : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 416 polygons
#>        $osm_multilines : NULL
#>     $osm_multipolygons : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 11 multipolygons
```

It's the same osmdata_sf object with more linestrings since some POLYGONS were actually converted into lines. Anyway now we can extract the LINESTRING component

```r
highways_castellon_lines <- highways_castellon$osm_lines
```

and plot it using several routines such as base R:

```r
par(mar = rep(0, 4))
plot(st_geometry(highways_castellon_lines))
```

[image]

Unfortunately there is a really small cluster of highways located far far away from the city center but we can easily remove it as follows:

```r
castellon_bbox <- st_bbox(highways_castellon_lines)

# Make the bbox a little bit smaller
castellon_bbox[3] <- 0.75 * castellon_bbox[3]

# crop
highways_castellon_lines <- st_crop(highways_castellon_lines, st_as_sfc(castellon_bbox))
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries

# Plot again: 
par(mar = rep(0, 4))
plot(st_geometry(highways_castellon_lines))
```

[image]

We can also use tmap:

```r
library(tmap)
tm_shape(highways_castellon_lines) + 
  tm_lines()
```

[image]

or ggplot2:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(highways_castellon_lines) + 
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

Final notes:

- There are a few warning messages here and there in the previous code but they are not super difficult to correct. The problem is that I'm not sure if this is useful for you or not.
- It may be difficult to download OSM data for bigger cities such as Rome, Barcellona, Madrid and so on. There are other approaches in those cases but it's difficult to help you without much much more details.

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Ok, I guess I need another step - see my edit to the question. Unfortunatelly, I can't share the osm-file. Do you have an idea, what's going on?

Comment: Can you try `sf::st_read("myfile.osm", options = c("OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO"))`?

Comment: It improved, but still does not work. See my Edit2 above. Thanks a lot for your help :-)